# Playing youtube in WPF application. Embedded video is not supported

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with an old WPF application i am building upon. When the application was made it was build to support playback of a Youtube video in an embedded WebBrowser control in WPF.

When im doing this now, then i get an error saying that this is not supported any longer. I have made a really simple implementation of this here: https://github.com/BHvarregaard/WPFYoutubePlayer/ - in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file i have the code:

```
string videoId = idtextBox.Text;            
            string videoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/v/{0}?version=3&playlist=1&hd=1&autoplay=1&fs=0&autohide=1&loop=1";
            string url = string.Format(videoUrl, videoId);
            browser.Source = new System.Uri(url);
```

Does anyone know how to do this or find another way of doing this. Right now i'm tied to the WPF application so i really would like to find the solution for WPF. The only other option i see would be to make a web based player of some sorts (maybe based on electron). But for now i really need a solution for the WPF.

The actual error i get in the code above is shown in the image below[image]

Comment: What exactly is the error you're receiving? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Updated with image of error

Comment: Try putting the query string parameter of "html5=1" on the end of the URL?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work :/ and trying Youtube's official embed url throws a script error. My guess is that the built in WPF browser just doesn't support playing these videos now that flash is no longer used. You may want to check https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27121/Stream-YouTube-Videos-in-WPF - you'll likely need to somehow get the URL to the video itself and then play that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely advise against using the default browser component in WPF (you will encounter script errors even just loading the youtube player). I have forked your GitHub project (see [here](https://github.com/VVlasy/WPFYoutubePlayer)), and used [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/) chromium component to display it.

NOTE: You cannot use Any CPU configuration with CefSharp!

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this. This might be the way to go.